# How make insert if select rows == '0' in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, I have the following:

Structure `Table`:

```
id(int primary key)
name(varchar 100 unique)
```

Values:

```
id  name

1   test
2   test1
```

I have two queries:

1) `SELECT count(*) FROM Table WHERE name='test'`

2) if `count` select rows == 0 second query `INSERT INTO Table (name) VALUES ('test')`

I know that may be use:

```
$res = mysql(SELECT count(*) as count FROM Table WHERE name='test');
// where mysql function make query in db

$i = $res -> fetch_assoc();

if($i['count'] < 1 ){$res = mysql(INSERT INTO Table (name) VALUES ('test');}
```

But I would like know how to make two query in one query.

How do I make one query inside of two?

Comment: What's your table definition? I.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: i edit post for specific reason, check please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `name` column has a `UNIQUE` constraint, just add `IGNORE` to the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table (name) VALUES ('test')
```

This will skip the insertion if a record already exists for a particular value and return 0 affected rows. Note that a primary key is also considered a `UNIQUE` constraint.

If the `name` column doesn't have such a constraint, I would advice that you add one:

```
ALTER TABLE `Table` ADD UNIQUE(name)
```

See also the documentation for [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a simple trick, like this:

```
insert into Table1(name)
select 'test' from dual
where not exists(select 1 from Table1 where name='test');
```

This will even work if you do not have a primary key on this column.

Explanation: `DUAL` is a special dummy table that is only referenced here to enable the `WHERE` clause. You would not be able to have a statement without a FROM clause (like `select 'test' where not exists(select 1 from Table1 where name='test')`) as it will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to check whether there is duplication, other's suggestion is good for  you. But you need, use 'INSERT' and check error number like this:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO ...');

if (mysql_errno() == 1062)
{
    echo "duplicated";
}
else
{
    echo "inserted";
}
```

(I know mysql_XXXX() is deprecated.. just example)

Comment: ...provided you pass in a primary key, which normally you wouldn't on an insert like this. Also, don't use **mysql** functions, they are deprecated.

Comment: @scrowler all of `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE ERROR` need that table has PK or UNIQUE. So I assuming so..

Comment: Your example doesn't though

Comment: @scrowler sorry, my English is bad. Could you elaborate on that? even if  table has PK or UNIQUE? My code could not check duplication error?

Comment: Take `INSERT INTO table(nonprimaryfield1, nonprimaryfield1, nonprimaryfield1) VALUES('john', 'test', 'hello')` - this will **never** throw a duplicate error, because the primary key will always increment. As this is the most common format for standard PHP SQL queries, you answer is not likely to be applicable in most cases.

Comment: @scrowler he didn't give us any information, there is AUTO_INCREMENT. If `name` is UNIQUE key, my query throws 1062 error.